# dual monitors not working with RHEL 6

Tags: redhat-enterprise-linux, multiple-monitors, setup

I installed REHL 6 (30 day demo version) on a system that already had 2 identical graphics cards. There are 2 identical monitors conneted, but only 1 monitor is detected. I tried System -> Preferences -> Display. It only shows 1 monitor, and "Detect Monitors" doesn't seem to do anything. Any idea what might be wrong, or how I might fix this? Is dual monitor support crippled in the demo version? I didn't find anything in the documentation that said it wouldn't work.

I'd like to add that this system used to run Solaris x86 with these 2 graphics cards. I'm looking at moving to RHEL if it can do everything Solaris can.

Comment: Can't you connect both monitors to one grapic card, I think that would be the easiest solution?

Comment: I'd like to make it work with the 2 card I already have. I'll buy a new card if that's the only to make it work.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have your video card drivers installed? At my job we have close to 30 machines running RHEL 6 with dual monitors. All of our machines are using nVidia video cards and I had to install it to get them to work properly, they displayed on both monitors without the drivers but were very glitchy. My suggestion is to go to your video card manufacturer's website and download their drivers from there instead of RHEL's repository.